# How to use lexer predicates to test against list of names?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have an `AvailableCommands` hash-set member. It's loaded with names before lexing/parsing starts from external source. How can I check if current `CMD` token exists in the set?

Something like:

```
CMD : [-_.0-9a-zA-Z]+ {AvailableCommands.Contains(/* what goes here? */);}?
    -> mode(IN_CMD)
    ;
```

I want to do it in the lexer because it's context-sensitive: command is lexed/parsed differently than, say, variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching a lexer rule constructs a Token that is available in `Lexer._token`.

```
CMD : [-_.0-9a-zA-Z]+ {AvailableCommands.Contains(_token.getText());}?
    -> mode(IN_CMD)
    ;
```

The [Antlr documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-LexerRuleActions) is fairly clear on point.

Comment: I think you can even use the language neutral notation `$text` instead.

Comment: No, attribute references are not currently supported in Antlr4 lexers.